# Writing results of some code

Tags: lists, algorithms, code

I am doing some homework on Newton's method and would like to display results after five (or so) iterations. I was hoping for something along the lines of

```
> 0.001
> 0.011
> 0.111
> 0.111
> 0.111
```

but the > sign looks a bit awkward. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\textsc{Newton$(1,2,5)$}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[$>$] $0.0001$
\item[$>$] $0.0011$
\item[$>$] $0.0111$
\item[$>$] $0.1111$
\item[$>$] $0.1111$
\end{enumerate}

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\textsc{Newton$(2,2,5)$}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[$>$] $0.0001$
\item[$>$] $0.0011$
\item[$>$] $0.0111$
\item[$>$] $0.1111$
\item[$>$] $0.1111$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like something for `listings` etc.

Comment: If this is output from a computer program you might want to consider sending that output to a file and then including the file verbatim in your document, rather than typing the numbers into the TeX source.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the > sign looks a bit awkward".

Comment: @Mico As it should, it looks like a greater than sign, but I want it to sort of look like a Mac terminal output.

Comment: I feel sort of stupid, but I don't know what a "Mac terminal output" looks like. Could you provide a link to a picture?

Comment: @Mico like this: http://imgur.com/uz6yZJV. It has more to do with the font, but I was looking for a more squished > sign.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\textsc{Newton(1,2,5)}}]
> 0.0001
> 0.0011
> 0.0111
> 0.1111
> 0.1111
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\textsc{reciprocal(2,2,5)}}]
> 0.0001
> 0.0011
> 0.0111
> 0.1111
> 0.1111
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

An update with some more graphical features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{macterminal}[1][]{enhanced,colback=white,colframe=blue, sharp corners,listing only, listing options={language=sh},every listing line={\bfseries\large\rmfamily >},#1}


\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C,keywordstyle={\bfseries},identifierstyle={\textrm}}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height]

\begin{macterminal}[title={\textsc{Newton(1,2,5)}}]
 0.0001
 0.0011
 0.0111
 0.1111
 0.1111
\end{macterminal}
\begin{macterminal}[title={\textsc{reciprocal(2,2,5)}}]
 0.0001
 0.0011
 0.0111
 0.1111
 0.1111
\end{macterminal}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway I can use the standard computer modern font for the numbers, however?

Comment: @user321210: Should be possible, I'll try to update. It's only one example, however.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment, consider using a plain `array` environment. (The horizontal bar in the following screenshot is added only to illustrate the width of the textblock.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule\smallskip % just to illustrate width of textblock

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}{c}
\textsc{Newton}(1,2,5)\\[1ex]
>0.0001\\
>0.0011\\
>0.0111\\
>0.1111\\
>0.1111\\
\end{array}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}{c}
\textsc{Newton}(2,2,5)\\[1ex]
>0.0001\\
>0.0011\\
>0.0111\\
>0.1111\\
>0.1111\\
\end{array}$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```